# Get current Windows 11 release in Python

Tags: python, windows-11

In Python 3.8.10 i cannot get the correct Windows release, i'm running Windows 11 Insider Preview, but the output says it Windows 10

[image: Bug]

Any WorkAround?

Edit: for now the only way i found to detect W11 is with

```
wmic os get name
```

Comment: [get buildnumber](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66555312/1466046) and if Build >= 22000 you use Windows 11 (preview)

Comment: there is a bug on this: https://bugs.python.org/issue45382

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution I used is the following:

```py
def is_win11():
    return sys.getwindowsversion().build >= 22000
```

And to know which type of Windows you have (e.g. Entreprise), you can use `platform.win32_edition()`.

Comment: According to MS, Windows 11 build numbers start at `22000`, not `20000`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/windows11-release-information?source=recommendations

Answer (score 1):

The [`platform.release()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#platform.release) call traces to [`win32_ver()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e41912c6348362489d2514565a70782591f23902/Lib/platform.py#L359) which then calls the C function [`sys_getwindowsversion_impl()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e41912c6348362489d2514565a70782591f23902/Python/sysmodule.c#L1495).

That C call simply pulls the version [**of `kernel32.dll` file**](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e41912c6348362489d2514565a70782591f23902/Python/sysmodule.c#L1534) i.e. not of the Windows itself by utilizing the [`GetFileVersionInfoW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winver/nf-winver-getfileversioninfosizew) + [`VerQueryValueW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winver/nf-winver-verqueryvaluew) Win32 API functions.

So until `kernel32.dll` file's version changes it'll remain Windows 10. Check manually if the result matches on that system and if it does not, open a bug for CPython.

Regarding whether this is the correct implementation or not I'd say is debatable. Apparently [it was in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47583450/5994041) but now it's not, so I guess just use [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) for [`GetProductInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724358(v=vs.85).aspx) or pull it from the registry.

However, you are using a preview version, which is one of the reasons the version might be "incorrect" because perhaps the Windows developers ***intend*** it to still be 10 instead of 11 and somewhere in the system there's a flag saying it's a "10" + "preview".

Comment: I tested the C Functions but gives the same value, the problem is really with kernel32 version, the only way i found to detect Win11 is with: wmic os get name